# Remove newline from a filed in MySQL table using query

Tags: mysql, newline, data-cleaning

I have a table in MySQL. I have a record for comments and because it comes from a textarea it contains newline character. Now when I want to export it as CSV, I have a problem.

Is there a query to replace all newline characters with space or another character?

Answer (score 0):

(1) create a user-defined function in MySQL that replaces what ever you want with what ever you want and call it what ever you want :D

```html
delimiter $$
create function removeNewLine (str text charset utf8) returns text charset utf8
begin
 declare ret text charset utf8;
 set ret = replace(str, "\r\n", "your char here");
    set ret = replace(str, "\r", "your char here");
    set ret = replace(str, "\n", "your char here");
 return ret;
end $$
```

(2) now all you have to do is to call that function on what ever column you want 
`select removeNewLine (table.bla1), removeNewLine (table.bla2) from table...`

Comment: and you can change the data type of the function input to varchar or anything that suits your use